# Netezza - reuse common sql code across multiple queries in a DRY manner?

Tags: sql, netezza

Is it possible with Netezza queries to include sql files (which contain specific sql code) or it is not the right way of usage ?

Here is an example.

I have some common sql code (lets say `common.sql`) which creates some temp table and needs to be used across multiple other queries (lets say `analysis1.sql`, `analysis2.sql` etc.) - . From a code management perspective it is quite overwhelming to maintain if the code in `common.sql` is repeated across the many other queries. Is there a `DRY` way to do this - something like `#include <common.sql>` from the other queries to call the reused code `common.sql` ?

Answer (score 0):

Including sql files is not the right way to do it.  If you wish to persist with this you could use a preprocessor like cpp or even php to assemble the files for you and have a build process to generate finished ones.

However from a maintainability perspective you are better off creating views and functions for reusable content.  Note that this can pose optimization barriers so large queries are often the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, views, functions (table values if needed) or more likely: stored procedures is the way to go.
We have had a lot of luck letting stored procedures generate complex but repeatable code patterns on the fly based on input parameters and metadata on the tables being processed.

An example: all tables has a 'unique constraint' (which is not really unique, but that doesn't matter since it isn't enforced in Netezza) that has a fixed name of UBK_[tablename]
UBK is used as a 'signal' to the stored procedure identifying the columns of the BusinessKey for a classic 'kimball style' type 2 dimension table.
The SP can then apply the 'incoming' rows to the target table just by being supplied With the name of the target table and a 'stage' table containing all the same column names and data types.

Other examples could be a SP that takes a tablename and three arguments each with a 'string,of,columns'  and does a 'excel style pivot' with group-by on the columns in the first argument and uses the second argument as to do a 'select distinct' to generate new column names for the pivoted columns, and does a 'sum' on the column in the third argument into some target table you specify the name for...

Can you follow me?

I think that the nzsql command line tool may be able to do an 'include', but a combination of strong 'building block stored procedures' and perl/python and/or an ETL tool will most likely proove a better choice